# what are side effects Connection Pooling with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, connection-string, connection-pooling

in asp.net c# project and sql server 2008r2 and ado.net i was added and increase maxpoolsize attribute
in connection string and my time out issue hass been fixed but i read this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
completely but there is no reference about side effect for increasing.

for compare these situation increase and decrease max pool size i was testing my query with 
this stored [procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) from sql server .

Answer (score 0):

if there is open and usable connection, connection pool provides that you can use them again. So it increases the performance.

Use Sql Stored procedure for database process. It is the best way for performance and security! But Don't forget to close the connection =)